# Get the data of the last 10 minutes with one row per minute [SQLite]

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would need to get the data of the last 10 minutes with one data per minute in SQLite, SELECT clause, for example like this:

```
06/12/2021 11:37:00 ...
06/12/2021 11:38:00 ...
06/12/2021 11:39:00 ...
06/12/2021 11:40:00 ...
06/12/2021 11:41:00 ...
```

Comment: Ok, great! You’ve told us what you *need*, but what’s your question? There doesn’t appear to be a complete or clear problem statement here. Please familiarize yourself with [ask]

Comment: I don't know how to make this query, i need the query :)

Comment: You don't need to attack me like this, I tried with my skills to make this query, but I couldn't, so I ask you for help...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column >= datetime('now', '-10 minutes', 'localtime');
```

Also have a look on https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.

Comment: This query return only the rows of last 10 minutes, i need this data, but with an interval of 1 minute

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve and what other data you have in the table. Because you can group by time function (eg. strftime()), but you have to decide what function to use for the other meaningful columns in the table (eg. SUM(), AVG()...).

Comment: I have a table that collects a lot of data per minute, I would like that for a time interval of X minutes (for example 10 minutes), only 1 data per minute would be extracted. So for a time interval of ten minutes you have 10 data

Comment: @ale we need a simple sample table that shows us what data you have (ideally without any unimportant columns). I can sort of understand what your table looks like from your written description but it'll be very helpful to have a simple `CREATE TABLE example …` and `INSERT INTO example …` script that we can run and test suggestions.